# How to create privilege (per user) in Kibana

Tags: authentication, elasticsearch, docker, kibana, privileges

I have a Docker of Elastic and a Docker of Kibana. I want to limit the access to Elastic,like user: admin can do: a, b, c and user: dev can do only: a.
How can i do it? What is the simple (complete)?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried any attempts?

Comment: Yes. I tried using Search-Guard, but failed to connect from Kibana to Elastic...

Comment: I tried to ask you for some code to paste, as this could be code based issue. Check this link http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and this http://stackoverflow.com/tour to learn how to post a good question.